# How to add Zeppelin to CDH 'by the book'?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, apache-zeppelin

There are many tools You can instal via Cloudera Manager, but Zeppelin in missing on the list. What is a best way to add Zeppelin to Cloudera CDH stack? I found some docs in internet, but they are a bit manual. I'm looking for a managed solution.

Answer (score 2):

CDH supports Hue for the notebook environment.

Cloudera Manager has no Zeppelin Parcel support, as far as I know.

I'm not sure what you mean by "managed solution", but automating an install of Zeppelin (and Spark), configuring to point at an external YARN master for job submission isn't too complicated, and can be written in Puppet, Chef, or Ansible fairly easily if you know those tools.

Comment: By managed solution I mean something like more or less official way, not own crafted solution. Something that will be aligned to CDH lifecycle, maitenance and updates.

Comment: Since Cloudera does not support Zeppelin, bundle it with CDH, or provide a parcel as mentioned, I doubt you would find such a solution. You're more than welcome to create a JIRA issue for Zeppelin asking for a Cloudera CDH Parcel, but someone would have to ensure it handles CDH / Zeppelin upgrades, and service monitoring + config management in Cloudera Manager, which is more Cloudera's deal than Zeppelin.

Comment: Thanks for answer. If You know any decent guide, how to install int manually, please share this for future and for others.

Answer (score 1):

There is https://github.com/ssheremeta/zeppelin-cloudera which allows you to package Zeppelin into the Cloudera Parcel (works well with 8), however I stumbled upon some issues, when trying to add Spark interpreter to the instance installed like that.

EDIT: Parcel format is described here: https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki
It's fairly complicated, but it allows you to have fully cloudera-managed-parcel made from whatever you want. 
You will need to write few scripts and service definition file - but it allows you to automate some things that normally you need to do yourself.